# Debian modem problem

Tags: linux, debian, kde, modem, ppp

I'm a new `Debian` user, it looks like a very good choice 4 me, every thing is stable, free and easy to use.

The problem is, I'm using my modem to establish a dial up connection to the internet `(ppp)` (a very old stupid way I'm forced to use for now), and using the `KPPP` application to do that, and nothing is working properly for me.
it seems like it didn't recognize my modem or something.

I already tried to make a few stuff, and now i know my modem is on `/dev/tty0`, so i made a link for that on `/dev/modem`, and query the modem using `KPPP` and it responded with something like:

```
Ati :

Ati0:

Ati1:


...

...

Ati7:
```

with a `textBox` to fill up in front of each one of thees `Ati`s, and now, when i press connect on `kppp`, it says modem ready, and that's it.

BTW, my modem is `MDC AC'97`

Comment: are you sure your modem is `/dev/tty0`?  that device is probably your console.  linux serial ports are more likely `/dev/ttyS0` or `/dev/ttyS1` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

> BTW, my modem is MDC AC'97

Hm, that is one of those infamous [softmodems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmodem). As far as I can tell, you have a *LSI/Agere MDC Softmodem*. There are no official Linux drivers for these. There are some drivers available, but as they need to hook into the Linux kernel, they can be tricky to install. See e.g. http://www.modemsite.com/56K/lucentamr.asp for details.

If you (or your distribution) have not installed these drivers, your modem will not work.

A pragmatic workaround would be to just buy a regular modem. A good old analog modem sells on Ebay or similar for around 10 $ (used). If it uses a serial (RS-232) connection, there will be minimal headache. USB modems can also work, but many need a special driver, so google Linux compatibility before buying.

That may not be an option if your computer does not have a free serial port, but if it does, it's probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you can communicate with the modem then chances are that you already have the driver loaded. I'm not clear on the above - do you have values after each of the AT commands you listed?

See: http://linmodems.org/ for more info about drivers.

If I remember my modem days properly (and they've been easy to forget), I think that at this point all you might need is a good init string for your modem. You should look into how to configure the dialer software that you're using.

Good luck.